# How to load octave-mode

Tags: octave, auto-mode-alist

I'd like to use the octave mode for emacs. There is no `octave-mode` package in MELPA, but EmacsWiki (https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/OctaveMode) and the emacs manual seem to suggest that it is built-in for v21 and higher (I have v28). However, simply opening a `.m` file does not activate it.

Even adding the following to `.emacs` does not work:

```
(autoload 'octave-mode "octave-mod" nil t)
(setq auto-mode-alist
      (cons '("\\.m$" . octave-mode) auto-mode-alist))
```

The error is: `File mode specification error: (file-missing Cannot open load file No such file or directory octave-mod)`, which does not make sense if the package is built-in.
Am I missing something?

Comment: The file is `octave.elc`, so try `(require 'octave)`. You can use `locate-library` to see if the library exists and what it is called (it allows completion with TAB). The autoload probably indicates that there is no entry for `.m` files in `auto-mode-alist`; try adding it with `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.m$" . octave-mode))` and see if that works.

Comment: The `require` shouldn't be necessary, octave-mode is autoloaded by default. So just evaluate the `add-to-list` form from @NickD's comment, before opening the .m file.

Comment: Yes - the `require` is a debugging step: if that succeeds, then the library exists. The next step then would be to see why the autoload did not work: checking `auto-mode-alist` to see if it contains that entry would do that. Strictly speaking, neither step should be necessary: `auto-mode-alist` should include the entry and the library should be autoloaded. Thanks for clarifying!'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.m$" . octave-mode))` to `.emacs` as suggested in the comments, has solved the problem!